# Giving individual particles cloth physics, and alternatives?

Tags: modifiers, particles, physics, cloth-simulation, instances

I wanna make a slime type creature that leaves behind puddles of slime as it jumps around the scene. I had the idea of attaching a particle system that emits cloth-physics spheres that collapse when they hit the ground. I have the sphere with the cloth settings I like (left,) but the emitter doesn't produce its own instances of the sphere so the particles simply copy the state and position of the reference(right.) My goal is to have an emitter that produces individual spheres that each have their own states, so my slime can leave a trail. Does anyone know how I should go about this? Is an emitter the right way to go, or is there another way for me to spawn these puddle spheres throughout the animation?[image]

Comment: This is a very difficult and impractical way to go about this . I suggest using dynamic paint with a displacement modifier instead.

Comment: Hm, I never looked into dynamic painting before, but after some initial research it looks way more optimized than what I have going on now. I found a solution using animation nodes to duplicate the reference mesh and replace the particles with the duplicates, but I will definetly look into dynamic paint/displacement and do some comparisons to try and get similar results. If I can get results looking similar to what I already have, it would definitely make my animation go a lot smoother!

Comment: If you got some solution don't hesitate to answer your own question so others can learn from you. Thanks :)